# How to implement audio streaming app and secure storage in flutter

Tags: android, swift, flutter, dart

I am about to build an app like deezer using flutter https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=deezer.android.app now for I have 2 question.

1. Is there any library for online audio streaming which may give the possibility to download the app
2. How can I store my audio files in a private / hidden folder such as folder created using vault app in case of download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.ps

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stream audio you can use this library:

[AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer)

To keep your files safe you can use the `Sandbox` folder in iOS and `getExternalFilesDir` in Android.

You can find an example of how to implement the saving of the file over here:

[Saving data to Local Storage in Flutter](https://medium.com/kick-start-fluttering/saving-data-to-local-storage-in-flutter-e20d973d88fa)

I remind you that SOF is to show what you've done so far, some of your progress, examples, etc so we can help you with that and not how to build an entire app.

Comment: Thanks guy. I know about SOF use case. I just wanted the main road for this as you showed. thanks again